# Why the userId is null when refresh the page? Is it a problem with the getting local storage data from the browser?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  Input,
  Col,
  Form,
  Space,
  Button,
  Menu,
  message,
  Rate,
  Spin,
} from "antd";
import { useAuthContext } from "../../Hooks/useAuthContext";
import Reviews from "./Reviews";
import SocialAccounts from "./SocialAccounts";
import "./AntMenu.css";
import newRequest from "../../Utils/newRequest";

import "./HeadCoachProfile.css";

//AVATAR

const onFinish = (values: any) => {
  console.log(values);
};

const DISPLAY_SIZES = {
  xs: { span: 22, offset: 1 },
  sm: { span: 16, offset: 4 },
  md: { span: 12, offset: 6 },
  lg: { span: 12, offset: 6 },
  xl: { span: 12, offset: 6 },
};

const HeadCoachProfile = () => {
  const img1: string = new URL(`../profile.png`, import.meta.url).href;
  const { userData } = useAuthContext();

  let userId = useRef<string>(userData?._id);

  const [fName, setFName] = useState<string>("Chanaka");
  const [lName, setLName] = useState<string>("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState<string>("");
  const [moNumber, setMoNumber] = useState<string>("");
  const [whatsAppNumber, setWhatsAppNumber] = useState<string>("");

  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
  const [gender, setGender] = useState<string>("");
  const [fb, setFb] = useState<string>("");
  const [insta, setInsta] = useState<string>("");
  const [tiktok, setTiktok] = useState<string>("");

  //new values
  const [newfName, setNewFName] = useState<string>("Chanaka");
  const [newlName, setNewLName] = useState<string>("");
  const [newAge, setNewAge] = useState<string>("");
  const [newMoNumber, setNewMoNumber] = useState<string>("");
  const [newWhatsAppNumber, setNewWhatsAppNumber] = useState<string>("");
  const [newGender, setNewGender] = useState<string>("");
  const [newFb, setNewFb] = useState<string>("");
  const [newInsta, setNewInsta] = useState<string>("");
  const [newTiktok, setNewTiktok] = useState<string>("");

  const [selectedMenu, setSelectedMenu] = useState<string>("user");
  const [rating, setRating] = useState<number>(4);

  const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userData) {
      userId.current = userData?._id;
    }
    setIsloading(true);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await newRequest.get(`/users/coach/${userId.current}`, {});
        console.log(res.data);
        setFName(res.data.firstName);
        setLName(res.data.lastName);
        setAge(res.data.age);
        setMoNumber(res.data.moNumber);
        setWhatsAppNumber(res.data.whatsApp);
        setEmail(res.data.email);
        setGender(res.data.gender);
        setFb(res.data.facebook);
        setInsta(res.data.instagram);
        setTiktok(res.data.tiktok);
        setIsloading(false);
      } catch (err: any) {
        message.error(err.message);
        setIsloading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const updateDetails = async () => {
    setIsloading(true);
    try {
      const res = await newRequest.post(
        `/users/coach/details/${userId.current}`,
        {
          firstName: newfName === "" ? fName : newfName,
          lastName: newlName === "" ? lName : newlName,
          age: newAge === "" ? age : newAge,
          moNumber: newMoNumber === "" ? moNumber : newMoNumber,
          whatsApp:
            newWhatsAppNumber === "" ? whatsAppNumber : newWhatsAppNumber,
          gender: newGender === "" ? gender : newGender,
          facebook: newFb === "" ? fb : newFb,
          instagram: newInsta === "" ? insta : newInsta,
          tiktok: newTiktok === "" ? tiktok : tiktok,
        }
      );
      message.success(res.data);
      setIsloading(false);
    } catch (err: any) {
      message.error(err.message);
      setIsloading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Spin spinning={isLoading}>
        <Space
          direction="vertical"
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            paddingTop: "10px",
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <img
              src={img1}
              style={{
                width: "100px",
                height: "100px",
                borderRadius: "50%",
              }}
            />
          </div>

          <Col
            {...DISPLAY_SIZES}
            style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
          >
            <Rate allowHalf disabled defaultValue={rating} />
          </Col>
          <p style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            Welcome {fName}
          </p>
          <div>
            <Col {...DISPLAY_SIZES}>
              <Menu
                style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
                theme="light"
                mode="horizontal"
                defaultSelectedKeys={["user"]}
                onClick={({ key }) => {
                  setSelectedMenu(key);
                }}
                items={[
                  {
                    label: "User Details",
                    key: "user",
                  },
                  { label: "Contact", key: "contact" },
                  { label: "Accounts", key: "socialAccounts" },
                  { label: "Reviews", key: "reviews" },
                ]}
              ></Menu>
            </Col>

            <Form
              name="form_item_path"
              onFinish={onFinish}
              layout="horizontal"
              labelCol={{ span: 6 }}
              labelAlign="left"
            >
              <Space direction="vertical" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                {selectedMenu === "user" && (
                  <div>
                    <Col {...DISPLAY_SIZES}>
                      <Form.Item label="First Name">
                        <Input
                          style={{ borderRadius: "0px" }}
                          value={fName}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            setNewFName(e.target.value);
                          }}
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                    <Col {...DISPLAY_SIZES}>
                      <Form.Item label="Last Name">
                        <Input
                          style={{ borderRadius: "0px" }}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            setNewLName(e.target.value);
                          }}
                          value={lName}
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                    <Col {...DISPLAY_SIZES}>
                      <Form.Item label="Age">
                        <Input
                          style={{ borderRadius: "0px" }}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            setNewAge(e.target.value);
                          }}
                          value={age}
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Col>

                    <Col {...DISPLAY_SIZES}>
                      <Form.Item label="Gender">
                        <Input
                          style={{ borderRadius: "0px" }}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            setNewGender(e.target.value);
                          }}
                          value={gender}
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                  </div>
                )}
                {selectedMenu === "contact" && (
                  <div>
                    <Col {...DISPLAY_SIZES}>
                      <Form.Item label="Mobile">
                        <Input
                          style={{ borderRadius: "0px" }}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            setNewMoNumber(e.target.value);
                          }}
                          value={moNumber}
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                    <Col {...DISPLAY_SIZES}>
                      <Form.Item label="WhatsApp">
                        <Input
                          style={{ borderRadius: "0px" }}
                          value={whatsAppNumber}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            setNewWhatsAppNumber(e.target.value);
                          }}
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Col>

                    <Col {...DISPLAY_SIZES}>
                      <Form.Item label="email">
                        <Input
                          style={{ borderRadius: "0px" }}
                          value={email}
                          disabled
                        />
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                  </div>
                )}

                {/* Reviews */}
                {selectedMenu === "reviews" && (
                  <Col {...DISPLAY_SIZES}>
                    {" "}
                    <Reviews />
                  </Col>
                )}

                {/* Social Accounts */}
                {selectedMenu === "socialAccounts" && (
                  <Col {...DISPLAY_SIZES}>
                    {" "}
                    <SocialAccounts
                      fb={fb}
                      setFb={setNewFb}
                      insta={insta}
                      setInsta={setNewInsta}
                      tiktok={tiktok}
                      setTiktok={setNewTiktok}
                    />
                  </Col>
                )}
                {!(selectedMenu === "reviews") && (
                  <>
                    <Col {...DISPLAY_SIZES}>
                      <Form.Item>
                        <button
                          className="coach-details-update-btn"
                          onClick={updateDetails}
                        >
                          Save Changes
                        </button>
                        <button className="coach-details-cancell-btn">
                          Cancell
                        </button>
                      </Form.Item>
                    </Col>
                  </>
                )}
              </Space>
            </Form>
          </div>
        </Space>
      </Spin>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HeadCoachProfile;
```

Issue with retrieving user ID from local storage resulting in Axios error

Body:
Hello,

I'm encountering an issue with retrieving the user ID from local storage in my browser. Whenever I refresh the page, the user ID becomes undefined, leading to an Axios error where I'm trying to read properties of null. I believe there might be a mistake in my implementation.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

I'm storing the user ID in local storage using the setItem() method.
When retrieving the user ID using the getItem() method, it works fine initially.
However, upon refreshing the page, the user ID becomes undefined, causing the Axios error in my subsequent request.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Here's the relevant code snippet:

javascript
Copy code
// Code snippet where I retrieve the user ID from local storage

const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
// Perform Axios request using the retrieved userId

Additionally, I've considered the following approaches, but I'm unsure if they are the correct solution:

Checking if the user ID exists in local storage before making the request.
Redirecting the user to a login page if the user ID is undefined.
Ensuring proper server-side validation of the user ID.
Could you please point out any mistakes I may have made in my implementation and provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: A couple debug thoughts:
1. Could it be that you're running setItem() and resetting the localstorage when refreshing the page?
2. After refreshing the page, can you still see inside of your console -> Application that the localstorage item is in fact not undefined?

Comment: Yes they can see it in the Application window in the browser